# Is it safe to use a different power adapter for my router?

Tags: router, power-supply

Can I use this adapter for my router:

```
Input:  150-300v - 50hz 500mA
Output: 12.0v -- 1.2A
```

Adapter instead of this broken one:

```
Input:  100-240v - 50/60Hz 0.3A
Output: 9v -- 0.6A
```

Comment: What's the router ask for? Check the bottom or stickers to see the specs, the old one would be ideal to match and gives a good read but the router should say exactly what is **required**.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot use that adapter because it is outputting more voltage than the original (12v vs. 9v).  This has a likely chance of burning out one or more of the components within the router.  In order to swap out chargers, 3 things must be the same:

- The output voltages must be identical
- The output amperage of the new one must be equal or greater than the original
- The new adapter must have the same tip polarity

There is some wiggle room in the amperage, but the voltage and tip polarity **must** match.  Tip polarity can usually be seen as a symbol like this:

[image]

In this picture, it indicates that the tip is negative.  Mixing tip polarities is just as likely to fry your router as using too high a voltage.

If replacing the power supply direct from the manufacturer is too expensive, try an electronics shop like RadioShack.  They typically sell universal plugs that can be used for any device.  Sometimes they even have selectable voltage and tip polarity.

Comment: My router needs 12v 500ma Adapter.. Can i use 12v 1A adapter ??

Answer (score 5):

NO!

Your output voltage is wrong, which is the important part. You can safely use an adapter with the same output voltage, and a current (A/mA) rating equal or higher than the original.

Comment: :((
what kind of damage does it cause ?
what other choice do I have than buying a new one?

Comment: @mixfuel besides getting a replacement adapter the other choices would be no longer using the router or replacing it entirely

Comment: This is probably too emphatic.  It _might_ work, depending on how the router was designed.  It's not that hard to design a voltage regulator into a box, precisely so it can be powered by a range of sources.  (Manufacturers like knowing they can substitute if they encounter a problem with a vendor supplying an important part.)  If the alternative is throwing away the router and buying a new one or buying a new power supply that costs more than the router is worth, meaning it's junk anyway, I would give it a try.  It might burn it out but it might work.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton - you're right, that was a bit dramatic. Some devices can handle a wide input range, but if you get unlucky you risk releasing the magic smoke ;)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't.  It might work depending on whether there's sufficient additional voltage regulation inside your router.  But the adapter you're considering using puts out a higher voltage than the original, 12v versus 9v, and stands a good chance of burning up your router with higher current than intended.

(Ohm's law says I = E/R.  If the load resistance, R, is constant but you increase the voltage, E, you will increase the current, I.)

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you are going to use another adapter use one with the same voltage and at least the same amperage.

- If you use one with less amperage then the device might try draw more juice and burn out the new adapter.
- If you use one with less voltage then it may fail to power the device. Not sure if that would damage it or if it just would not work
- If you use one with **significantly more voltage** (and 12v is a full third more than 9v) then you might burn out your device.

Your situtation:
Old output: 9v and 0.6A
New output 12v and 1.2A

The third reason is why you do not want to test this.

Comment: Seems like I need to buy a new one! :(